# TypeORM: when should I prefer entity.find() over entity.createQueryBuilder()?

Tags: typeorm

In TypeORM, to find an entity row:

method 1:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
  where: { 'username': username }
});
```

method 2:

```
const user = await User.createQueryBuilder('user')
  .select()
  .where('user.username = :value', { value: username })
  .getOne();
```

Are they equal?

In terms of performance, which one is better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the different use cases for using QueryBuilder vs. Repository in TypeORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722202/what-are-the-different-use-cases-for-using-querybuilder-vs-repository-in-typeor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equal.

The QueryBuilder API is more powerful than the Repository API, in terms of more complex SQL queries.

Refer to the existing question:

[What are the different use cases for using QueryBuilder vs. Repository in TypeORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58722202/10158227)